# Any difference between "Sorry I'm late!" and "Sorry for being late!"?

Tags: formality, gerunds, subordinate-clauses

Is one of these sentences used more than the other?

> - (I'm) sorry I'm late.
> - (I'm) sorry for being late.

Or is one more formal than the other?

Comment: The former can only be said at the moment of being late whilst the latter can be said any time after the fact.

Comment: Agree. "Sorry I'm late" is usually said when you arrive.

Comment: Agree. Otherwise it would be "Sorry I was late".

Comment: And "I'm sorry for being late" connotes more contrition than "Sorry I'm late", in my view.

Comment: That's also a good point.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: so, it is more ceremonious, more formal?

Comment: @Dominic: a kind of belated apology, then… ?

Comment: @PeterShor: then again arises the question of whether to say "Sorry I was late." or "Sorry for being late." and which is the most common, or what are the nuances, the shades of meaning between them?

Comment: "Sorry I'm late" (especially with no comma / pause) sounds clipped, almost dismissive to me (though it depends greatly on intonation when spoken, as is usually the case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither expression is really that formal, in my opinion. A more formal expression could be,

> "I sincerely apologize for being late."

Or,

> "I sincerely apologize for having been late."

Or possibly,

> "I apologize; I'm late."

Or,

> "I'm late; I apologize."

Actually, I prefer the latter over the former.

Comment: Taking the other comments into account, could the first two sentences be said to be a belated apology and the last two an on-the-spot one?

Comment: @user58319: Yes, the first two could be uttered belatedly, but the second of the two even more so. In each case, the words "this morning" (or something similar) added to the sentences, say, later in the day (e.g., at 3:00 PM) would make them belated apologies. Yes, the last two are appropriate for an on-the-spot apology in the present.